# Firebase Realtime Database Rules Based On Specific Data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to set up data access rules for a Realtime Database property based on a specific piece of data that the user is requesting?

For example, I'm an authenticated user (using Firebase Authentication), and I'm querying a certain property from the database, like this:

```
firebase.ref('myLists').orderByChild('listId').equalTo('someString').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  // ...
})
```

In what ways can I use that `'someString'` value in Database Rules?

For `.write`, we have access to `data` and `newData`, but I don't think there is something similar for `.read`?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow this query, and only this query, by checking:

```
".read": "query.orderByValue === 'listId' && query.equalTo === 'someString'"
```

Of course this will still only return nodes that have a `listId` property with a `someString` value.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules).

Comment: Thanks Frank! I should have been more clear what I was after, which is "someString" is meant to be dynamic data, but your answer has pretty much covered that anyway, as you've mentioned "this query, and only this query".. I think I'll have to use Cloud Functions to control access and lose the realtime updates feature 